# != cannot be applied to operands of type Vector2 and Float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a dust particle whenever my character moves, and the best way that I have thought of to do that is to activate a method to spawn in the dust particle, however when I simply spawn it in when given the correct input, the particles continue to generate for several more seconds after I stop moving. I am now trying to spawn them whenever my characters velocity does not equal zero, but that isn't working due to the error message stated in the title.

```
body.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, body.velocity.y);

        if (body.velocity != 0f)
        {
            createDust();
        }
```

I have been unable to find a method to use the != operator to calculate this, and I have also tried

`if (body.velocity < 0f | body.velocity > 0f)`

but I get a similar error message about how the operator cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!Mathf.Approximately(body.velocity.magnitude, 0f))
{
    // your code here.
    Debug.Log("is not 0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self explanatory: A `Vector2` consists of **2** `float` components => you can't simply compare it to a single one.

An alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668846/7111561) (which probably is preferred most of the times) you could also do

```
if(body.velocity != Vector2.zero)
{
     createDust();
}
```

where

- [`Vector2.zero`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-zero.html) is a short for `new Vector2()` or also `new Vector2(0, 0)`
- [`Vector2 != Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_eq.html) includes already an approximation with a precision of `1e-5`.

  Internally it uses a square magnitude. So it is probably more or less as efficient as going through the `magnitude`

So basically this equals doing

```
if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.magnitude) <= 0.00001f)
{

}
```

while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668846/7111561) equals

```
if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.magnitude) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
{

}
```

where [Mathf.Epsilon](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) is the smallest value two `float`s can differ